# Apply a function every N data points

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, function

I have time series data as such:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range(freq=f'{1}T',start='2020-10-10',periods=(12)*24))
df['value'] = np.random.randint(1, 100, size= df.shape[0])

n_array=df.to_numpy().reshape(-1,)

                      value
2020-10-10 00:00:00    66
2020-10-10 00:01:00    4
2020-10-10 00:02:00    42
...
```

I want to apply a function to this time series data such as this:

```
def func(arr, b, c):
    return np.mean(arr) *b -c

func(n_array, 3, 5)
```

for every 10 minute interval in the time series data.

So, compute this value for every 10 data points, and write them in a dataframe with 10-min intervals. The input variable "arr" needs to be an array with the shape of (10,) for my purposes.

How can I achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Lets do resample and apply a custom func

```
df.resample('10min', origin='start')['value'].apply(func, 3, 5)
```

Result

```
2020-10-10 00:00:00    127.900
2020-10-10 00:10:00    143.200
2020-10-10 00:20:00    151.300
2020-10-10 00:30:00    154.600
...
2020-10-10 04:10:00    220.300
2020-10-10 04:20:00    195.700
2020-10-10 04:30:00    145.900
2020-10-10 04:40:00    133.375
Freq: 10T, Name: value, dtype: float64
```

Comment: The argument "arr" needs to be a 1d array, so I need to a "reshape(-1,)" to my data before applying the function.